# Uniform convergence (in t) of sum of random variables

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

assume i.i.d. random variables $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$ with mean 0 and variance 1. I am interested in $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{t\geq 0} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{nt}{X_i}}{\sqrt{nt}n^{1/5}}$. Does this expression converge to zero a.s.?

Comment: Actually this diverges to infinity with prob 1, since for any fixed integer $n$ we have  $\sup_{t\geq 0} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{nt} X_i}{\sqrt{nt} n^{1/5}} = \infty$ with prob 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $n$ as a positive integer. Consider $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, ...\}$ in blocks of size $n$, and define $Y_k$ as the sum over the $k$th block:

$$ Y_k = X_{(k-1)n+1} + X_{(k-1)n+2} + ... + X_{kn} $$

Then $\{Y_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is iid with $E[Y_k]=0$ and $Var(Y_k)=n$. For positive integers $t$, define $G_t$ by: 
$$ G_t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{nt}}\sum_{k=1}^{t} Y_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{nt}}\sum_{i=1}^{nt}X_i $$
Now, the central limit theorem says $G_t$ converges in distribution to a Gaussian with mean 0 and variance 1 as $t\rightarrow\infty$.   But it also holds (for example, by the Kolmogorov 0-1 law) that the limsup of $G_t$ is infinity with prob 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice explanation! In the case of $t$ is in a fixed interval $[0,S]$ with $S>0$ (i.e. look at $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{t \in [0,S]} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{nt}{X_i}}{\sqrt{nt}n^{1/5}}$) the argument with $t \to \infty$ cannot be used anymore in my opinion. So, does my assumption hold, when only $n$ tends to infinity and not $t$ ?

Comment: Let's take the sup over integers $t \in \{1, ..., S\}$. I think "yes" if the $X_i$ variables are deterministically bounded, so there is an $M$ such that $|X_i|\leq M$ for all $i$. The general case, I'm not sure...

Comment: For $t \in \{1, …, S\}$, divide $\{X_1, X_2, …\}$ into blocks of size $t$ and 
define $Y_i(t)$ as the sum over block $i$.  Then $\{Y_i(t)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are iid with 
$E[Y_i(t)]=0$ and $Var(Y_i(t))=t$.   It suffices to show that, for each $t \in \{1, \ldots, S\}$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{nt} n^{1/5}} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(t)=0$ with prob 1.  Define $R_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{nt} n^{1/5}} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i(t)$.  So $Var(R_n(t)) = \frac{1}{n^{2/5}}$.  Then $Var(R_{n^5}(t))$ is summable over $n$, and by Chebyshev we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}R_{n^5}(t)=0$ with prob 1.

Comment: I think boundedness of $|X_i|$ and convergence over the subsequence $n^5$ then further implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} R_n(t) = 0$ with prob 1.